# IllegalAnnotationExceptions in JUnit test

Tags: java, junit, jaxb

I want to create JUnit test to Test JAXB code:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "reconcile")
public class Reconcile {

    @XmlElement(name = "start_date")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateTimeXmlAdapter.class)
    public LocalDateTime start_date;
    @XmlElement(name = "end_date")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateTimeXmlAdapter.class)
    public LocalDateTime end_date;
    @XmlElement(name = "page")
    public String page;

    //// getters and setters
}
```

I tried this JUnit test for the above code:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

import org.datalis.plugin.reconcile.Reconcile;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class ReconciliationTest {

    @Test
    public void uniqueTransactionIdLenght() throws JAXBException {

        Reconcile reconcile = new Reconcile();
        reconcile.start_date = LocalDateTime.of(2018, 4, 8, 11, 2, 44);
        reconcile.end_date = LocalDateTime.of(2018, 11, 8, 11, 2, 44);
        reconcile.page = "1";

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Reconcile.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.marshal(reconcile, System.out);
    }
}
```

But when I run the code I get:

```
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 3 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
    at org.datalis.plugin.jaxb.ReconciliationTest.uniqueTransactionIdLenght(ReconciliationTest.java:22)
```

at this line

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Reconcile.class);
```

Is there some way to solve the issue?

Comment: Actually, your code works fine for me, with the only difference being the `LocalDateTimeXmlAdapter` class, since you didn't provide the source for it. I doubt that it would cause any problems, but could you add it for completeness?

Comment: It's from maven dependency: https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.migesok/jaxb-java-time-adapters/1.1.3/jar

Comment: Do you use the same imports?

Comment: Yes, I used the standard JAXB imports. Guess this could also depend on your Java version. What happens if you remove the adapter annotations? Same error?

Comment: I use Java 10 - latest

Comment: So what happens if you remove the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotations?

Comment: The same: `com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 3 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Class has two properties of the same name "end_date"
 this problem is related to the following location:
  at public java.time.LocalDateTime `

Comment: Which Java version do you use?

Comment: I removed getters and setters from the Tested class and it's working. Any idea how to implement the test with getters and setters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the error message you mention in the comments:

> Class has two properties of the same name "end_date" this problem is related to the following location: at public java.time.LocalDateTime

The problem is probably this:

You either don't have an `@XmlAccessorType` annotation (so that the default access type is used) or you do, but with the wrong access type.

Try putting this annotation on your class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
```

Explanation:

JAXB can treat your classes in different ways. It can either look at getter/setter pairs, or it can look at fields directly. This is the access type.

The default access type is `XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER` which is a bit strange: it will look at public getter/setter pairs as well as public fields.

If you put annotations such as `@XmlElement` on fields, but you also have getter/setter methods for those fields, then JAXB will find the getter/setter and it will also find the field because it's annotated explicitly, and then it will think there are two properties with the same name: one defined by the getter/setter, and one defined by the field.

The solution is to tell JAXB that it should look only at the fields, by using `XmlAccessType.FIELD`, or by putting the `@XmlElement` annotations on the getter or setter method instead of on the field.

It's a bit quirky, but that's how JAXB works...

Note that you can put the `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` not only on a class, but also on the whole package by putting it in a `package-info.java` file - that way you don't have to put it on every one of your domain model classes.